# How to include properties when using inheritance in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to use inheritance in EF and have come up with the following (simplified):

```
public abstract class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime ScheduledTime { get; set; }
}

[Table("InstallationJobs")]
public class InstallationJob : Job
{
    public PbnSite Site { get; set; }
}
```

And my dbcontext has the following:

```
public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
```

Now, I'm trying to get a random job (which I've previously inserted):

```
var job = _dbContext.Jobs.OrderBy(x => x.ScheduledTime).FirstOrDefault();
//logic to find out which job time was retrieved and then get the specific information
```

And that returns a job! However, when I cast the job to the correct job type (InstallationJob in this example), it doesn't have any information in regards to the Site property. (since I haven't included it).

But how would I go about including it seeing as Jobs is a generic table?

When the job is of childtype X I want to include the properties of X and when it is of Y I want to include the properties of Y.

Comment: I'll leave the answering to more experienced people as I thought a table-perheirarchy was the default (you are doing code-first, right?) and should be achieved with what you have (Based on: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) You could, of course, resolve it with a dbSet<InstallationJob> and move to a table-per-type approach but it should default to the former?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the derived object using `OfType` method

```
var job = _dbContext.Jobs.OrderBy(x => x.ScheduledTime)
                         .OfType<InstallationJob >
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I see. One question though: What if I wanted to get the job with the earliest scheduled time of ALL the jobs (regardless of the jobtype) and THEN convert the earliest job to it's specific type?

Comment: Hi, Jen, if this is a different issue, then create a new question, so I or some other people can help you.

Comment: Well, yes, you can *try* to convert it to a specific type, because this earliest job can be of any type.